# How to mimic iOS keyboard behavior with preview of the current item when holding the finger on it?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using Xcode to develop an app for iOS where the user can rate some content by touching the corresponding smiley icon (from frown to big smile). At the moment, each smiley icon behaves as a single button: when one of the smileys is touched, its color changes to show the user his/her choice.

However, being the icons small in the iPhone display, it is not easy to touch with precision the desidered smiley, and the user is likely to make errors.

I would like improve my rating system to mimic the behavior of the IOS keyboard for iPhone when it shows on top of the finger the selected character, and inputs the character just when the user releases the finger.

More precisely, I would like my 5 smiley items to behave not as separated buttons, but as a slider with 5 discrete points: when the user's finger is held on an item (covering it), a zoomed version on top appears, the user can continue sliding and when he/she releases the finger the selected item is chosen. I created a small animation to show what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Which method or class would you recommend to use to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go for popover controller. Here is what you can do.

Implement this method in your ViewController:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    for (UIImageView *sView in self.smileyImages)
    //smileyImages is outletCollection of smileyImageViews.
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([sView frame], point))
        {
            [self.popupView setHidden:NO];
            //popupView is the popup view you want to show.
            [self.popupImage setImage:[sView image]];
            //popupImage is enlarged image of smiley in popup view you want to show.

            CGPoint newCenter= CGPointMake(sView.center.x, sView.center.y-40);
            //This fixes position of your popupView.
            [self.popupView setCenter:newCenter];
        }
    }

}
```

[Here is the](https://github.com/achievelimitless/popupTest) Github of the code. I've just implemented popup for you. Rest you can do I think. If not, Let me know.

**Update:**

Add this method for desired results

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    for (UIImageView *sView in self.smileyImages)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([sView frame], point))
        {
            self.selectedImage= sView.image;
            [self.popupView setHidden:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update2:**
Previous update has some issues, go for this code instead:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.selectedImage= self.popupImage.image;
    [self.popupView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: So many thanks man! It works :) Although there is just one very small thing missing: when you release the finger the popup should disappear and the current item should be chosen. While currently when the finger the popup remains visible on the last item touched. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Albz ..Added code in answer as well as github. Feel free to accept answer if it helped ..:)

Comment: Your solution works great! Thank you also for sharing the Github repo with the code :)